# Is this a bug in lua, or a feature unknown to me?

Tags: debugging, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to teach a friend of mine how to lua, basically, and he comes to me with this code, and it stumps my head:

```
a = {name = "aaa"}

function a:new()
  self.x = "sss"
  o = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end

function a:some()
  return "[ " .. self.name .. " ]"
end

b = a:new()
print(b:some())
print(b.x)
```

which prints

`[ aaa ] 
sss`

both shouldnt be possible, since they were never set to `o` inside `a:new`

after some debugging, i look into it, and here some interesting things happen:

```
a = {name = "aaa", x = "sss"}

function a:new()
  o = {}
  print(o.x, self.x)
   -- nil sss
  setmetatable(o, self)
  print(o.x, self.x, o, self, self.__index, o.__index)
   -- nil sss table: 0x1001280 table: 0x1001320 table: 0x1001320 nil
  self.__index = self
  print(o.x, self.x, o, self, self.__index, o.__index)
   -- sss sss table: 0x1001280 table: 0x1001320 table: 0x1001320 table: 0x1001320
  return o
end
```

Note how on the third `print`, it returns the `.x` value of `self`, but it was called from `o`, which has no "relationship" with self, how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You've set table `a` as `__index` field in metatable for all tables that will be created with `a:new()`. When some non-existent field will be checked in the `b` table, value will be searched in `a` too. That's why you can find fields `x` or `name` in a table `b`, even if you didn't assign it explicitly.

Comment: how is setting `self` to `self.__index` setting it for all tables? the most i expect from that is setting a recursive `__index`, nothing more

Comment: `b = a:new()` is equivalent to `b = a.new(a)`, where `a` will be passed as the first argument, which is `self`. So when you do `setmetatable(o, self)`, you're effectively doing `setmetatable(o, a)`. That's why `a`'s fields will be available to all objects created with `a:new()`

Comment: keep in mind that in the statement up there, `return o` is applied, which is a new object, and even if it returned a modified `a`, there is still the case of that `print` reporting weird stuff

Comment: Returned object `o` has metatable set, that metatable has `a` set as `__index` field. If later you will access some filed of that returned object, and that field doesn't exist - then `__index` kicks in, searching required field in `a` table. Note that in your latter example you will get "weird" outputs only after you've set `__index` field, and note before. Familiarize yourself with metatables and metamethods. That's chapter 2.4 of Lua's manuals.